# Return full nested object on aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I have the following document:

```
{
    "_index" : "test3_products",
    "_type" : "products",
    "_id" : "1",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "description" : "hihihi",
      "subCategories" : [
        {
          "name" : "Jeans",
          "value" : "jeans"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

And my aggregations is the following:

```
aggs: {
  nestedSubCategories: {
    nested: {
      path: 'subCategories',
    },
    aggs: {
      subCategories: {
        terms: {
          field: 'subCategories.value',
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

And the result I got is:

```
{
"nestedSubCategories": {
    "doc_count": 1,
    "subCategories": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": "jeans",
                "doc_count": 1
            }
        ]
    }
}}
```

However, I would like that the `key` could be something like: 
`key: {name: "Jeans", value: "jeans" }`

Is it possible to do something like that in Elastic Search?